# Data set for forecasting

Tags: time-series, forecasting, arima

I am looking for a data set which can be used for ARIMA or any forecasting models. The data should be such that, over a period of time the range of inputs change i.e. the band of input data changes significantly. This should lead to incorrect forecasting. I should see the error in forecasting and should retrain the model. I do not want to simulate and i am looking for some real world example.

Comment: Like the AirPassenger data in Box and Jenkins? Please note that this sort of question ... "*Where can I find data that fits these criteria*" doesn't seem to fall under the scope of CV as defined in the [faq](http://stats.stackexchange.com/faq#questions).

Comment: You can find here http://www.matteodefelice.name/research/resources/ electricity demand, ambient temperature and occupancy of a building inside my research centre. I've used such data for a paper about forecasting comparing neural networks with ARIMA models.

Answer (score 2):

Dr. Rob Hyndman has provided a Time Series Data Library [here](http://robjhyndman.com/TSDL/).